# getter/setter generation with multiline stringfy macro

Tags: c++, macros, getter-setter

I have recently seen a cool c style macro play which generates automatically the setters/getters for the class. So this is what I am talking about.

```
#define BOOL_VARIABLE(name)\
    void set##name(bool iValue)\
    {\
        // set the boolean
    }\ 
    const bool get##name() const\
    {\
       // get the boolean
    }

    BOOL_VARIABLE(AVariableName); // and calling them inside the class
```

- and now think about one of them for all string/int/double etc variables

I am aware of all avoid-macro usage type of remarks but I actually find it pretty cool because long getter/setter lines are really disturbing me. Can you think of anything that might go wrong with this approach.

Comment: @EdHeal :) is it the validation of inputs only or some other issues as well?

Comment: @ralzaul This type of code isn't very easily readable by others.  Functions generated by the preprocessor are less likely (won't be?) picked up by any tools which generate documentation, offer intellisense-type auto-complete, etc.  Also, obfuscating your code like this has prevented you noticing that the getter is returning by const value, something which gives no benefit to the implementor and  imposes needless restrictions on the caller. (You may want the getter for pointer types to return a const pointer; you probably don't want value types to do this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following* is a better option (with type also as a parameter). However, I would avoid implementations to take full advantage of accessor methods, as mentioned by @justin. Your compiler will generate errors if you forget to implement them.

*http://cppkid.wordpress.com/2008/09/04/getters-and-setters-for-a-class-using-a-macro/

```
#define GETSET(type, var) \         
    private: \         
       type _##var; \         
    public: \         
       type Get##var() \         
       {\         
          return _##var; \         
       }\
       void Set##var(type val) \         
       {\         
          _##var = val; \         
       }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is not a strong benefit over direct member access -- Why should it exist in the first place?

Typically, the body of the accessor is a good place for validation of inputs and state of `this,` but the macro does not allow that so it really does not contribute "enough" to use (IMO) across a codebase. In typical programs, there will also often be enough variation to not justify its usage. It certainly should not be the only way to declare a variable and/or its accessors.

Just so there is no confusion: I am all for accessors and encapsulation. This macro just locks you out of their more important benefits.