# Generic Mutator/Accessor functions

Tags: c++, accessor, mutators

Is there a way to create generic set/get functions in C++? I have a class with a large number of attributes but no functions (ok I should probably use a struct), and really don't want to write individual set and get functions for each data member. The functions I'm thinking of would be something like 'set_member( T variable ), where T could be anything, primitive types or user defined. I imagine perhaps you could create a struct with a struct as a member, then whenever you want to access a specific member of the member struct, you refer to it by the appropriate pointer. I've tried writing something to achieve this but no luck so far.

Comment: have you try macro ?

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: Java language recommends to always use accessors and mutators, and because of that most Jave IDE are able to automatically generate them. If you really want that, some IDE allow you to develop add-ons that will process the source code. If you want to use that as a re-usable design pattern, like respecting some Java usages in C++, it will probably make sense. Take some IDEs available in your platform, look at their already developped add ons, and make your decision. Only you can know if it is worth it.

Comment: If you need a get/set function pair for each data member, scrap your design and start over. You are just adding layers of useless wrappers. Design proper abstractions instead. Classes should have *behaviour*, rather than a dumb collection of field

Answer (score 1):

C++ has (as far as I know) no inbuilt way to autogenerate setter/getter functions.

You might be able to work some [macro-magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412266/getter-setter-generation-with-multiline-stringfy-macro) (with all its pitfalls), otherwise your options are slim.

Comment: What's the point of getters/setters when they're macro generated?

Comment: well, when you need to debug one of them, just remove the macro, add your debug, done. Auto generated set/get let you change your mind with little cost where public attribut dont

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. They've given me lots to think about.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of following alternatives:

1. Some IDEs generate get, set methods automatically for the data members of class. I am not sure if it is possible for C++ IDE. But I know that Eclipse IDE for Java does it. You may check once if Eclipse IDE for C++ has this facility.
2. You may write a short shell script or python script for automatically generating get, set method given a text file containing names and types of variables in each line.
3. By default all the members of struct are public. So use struct. Or if you decide to use class, then, put all the data members in public section. If you are not doing anything other than simple set, get, then, it might be ok to do so. However, debugging will be tedious in case if you encounter issues with changes in the data members.